# Excel cant change formula without error

Tags: excel, function

I am using this formula to check the value in cell B6 and then check through sheet 1 for all occurrences of that value. The formula works as expected. However,  want to copy the formula and change some functionality to it. However if I even change B6 to $B6 it breaks, If I copy it to another cell it breaks, if I simply click on the cell and press enter without making any changes ... it breaks. I don't understand this, obviously it is a bug but I don't know what is causing it. I'm not used to excel so I don't know if I it's me or the program.

```
=IFERROR(SUM(LEN(sheet1!$C$4:$AD$38)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(sheet1!$C$4:$AD$38,LEFT(B6,LEN(B6)),"")))/LEN(B6),0)
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

I also just noticed that the formula that is working is surrounded by curly braces

```
{=IFERROR(SUM(LEN(sheet1!$C$4:$AD$38)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(sheet1!$C$4:$AD$38,LEFT(B6,LEN(B6)),"")))/LEN(B6),0)}
```

Answer (score 1):

OK My mistake the reason this function cant be copied straight is because it is an array function and must be entered with Ctrl+Shift+Return

Apologies